# How to differentiate between closed and filtered remote ports

Tags: go, port, firewall

I am setting up port scanner for remote server in my application using Go. I am using DialTimeout function in Go net package to check whether a remote host port is opened or not. The result is fine with success case. But, if i/o timeout happens, I need to identify whether

1. The port is closed (No service is running) or
2. Port is blocked (Firewall filtered) or
3. Due to internet connectivity down in local system where the application is running.

Have tried nmap cli command, I can able to differentiate those failure 3 cases exactly.
nmap command tried: nmap -sA -p port_number host_ip

I found a Go 3rd party libray to use nmap.
But, I don't want to use nmap in my application. Are there any other alternatives in Go to exactly differentiate those 3 cases?

Comment: You can't. If the firewall leaks that information, it's a terribly broken firewall.

Comment: Even `nmap` states clearly in its documentation that there are various cases where it cannot determine conclusively if a port is closed or filtered. Most firewalls will simply time out a connection to a filtered port, leaving the cause of the timeout ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

### In the simple world

Lets assume you want to scan a Linux system.

If you get an [ICMP message type 3 code 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Control_messages), the firewall explicitly told you:

> Hi, I am the firewall of your target host. The host is running. I hereby inform you that you (potentially amongst others) can not access this port. So now that you know you should quit your connection attempts. However, I won't tell you wether it is because there is no service running behind it (in which case my response is simply a courtesy) or because I was told to deny you access. Goodbye!

The port is closed if you do not get above answer *and* can not make a connection. I hence strongly advice to use `context.WithTimeout` to make a connection.

### In the real world

However, this only applies if the admin of the target host did not change the ICMP message type to respond with - or chose just to drop any packets coming from sources which are not allowed to access the respective service. In the latter case, **there is no way** for you to know wether the port is closed or filtered.

All of the above only applies if we are talking of an iptables based firewall on the target system with default settings.

Now assume something which is by far more likely: A border firewall *plus* a local firewall. The border firewall might send other ICMP messages (or, again, simply drop your packages). Those rules apply additionally to the rules of the local firewall. So it is a misconception that you are actually scanning a host. It is more accurate to say that you scan the services reachable via a specific IP.

**EDIT**

### Why would one send an ICMP message explicitly rejecting connection attempts?

There are various reasons to come to that decision. There is a [good answer on serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/a/157418/238425)

Comment: Can you provide a further reference that ICMP type 3 code 3 means that? Your claim contradicts your link which says "Destination unreachable is generated by the host or its inbound gateway", so there's no implicit or explicit claim that "I am the firewall..."

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way to communicate over ICMP that "The service is running, but blocked." Which is what the OP is asking for. Even if it is possible to do that, most firewall implementations would be foolish to do so.

Comment: @Flimzy It is implicit, as detailed above. As per source: https://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/x4550.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197668/discussion-between-markus-w-mahlberg-and-flimzy).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Doubt regrading filtered and closed ports are clear. Let's assume 3rd case, either local system dont have internet connectivity or both inbound and outbound traffic from local machine to remote servers are blocked in local firewall(Either host based firewall or a hardware device). Need to return specific message to user that "you dont have internet connectivity to make remote connection" or "Your own firewall is blocking remote connection" in golang. Either one message i should return to user. Not like web browsers(Generic message firewall or internet down)

Comment: @VigneshG Well, test for connectivity is a totally different topic. I usually test the gateway and some well known IP like 8.8.8.8. As per my answer, it is impossible to know who blocks.

Comment: Even now i have that check only, ping to 8.8.8.8. But, Lets say source firewall blocks even ICMP and it allows only certain ports for their own private server connection(TCP/UDP). Remaining all ports are blocked. But, they have internet connectivity on their system. Is there a possible way to distinguish between, client does not have internet connectivity and client has internet connectivity but only restricted access is there.

Comment: Apart from using nmap is there any other way for this issue? If so how to achieve in golang.

Comment: @VigneshG And this is exactly the reason why multi-part questions a re frowned upon. Bottom line: You can not easily identify where you are blocked, and not reliably anyway. Try to find a solution for that issue yourself, present where your problems *with the code* are. What you have now is a mission statement and... ...nnothing ;)